# Port project from C++ Builder 2009 to C++ Builder 11

Tags: c++builder

I have a sizeable project that finally can be ported to the latest and greatest compiler version (11).

From your experience, is it a good idea to 'simply' open the project in the new compiler and let the compiler do its thing ?

Or do you recommend a different approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From your experience, is it a good idea to 'simply' open the project in the new compiler and let the compiler do its thing ?

Absolutely not.  That *rarely* works as expected.  Sure, it will *upgrade* the project file to the latest version, but that does not include updating component/library references, etc.  You have to do all of that by hand.

> Or do you recommend a different approach ?

Yes.  The standard advice for many many years is to create a new project fresh, and then add your existing source code/files to it as needed.

Comment: But what about the design time placement of various controls etc. ?

Comment: You can reuse existing DFMs

Comment: By simply copying the existing *.dfm over the newly created *.dfm ?

Comment: No, because there shouldn't be any "newly created *.dfm" to overwrite to begin with. Remove any default-generated Forms from the new project, and then add your existing Forms and DFMs to the project.